# How to compute $\text{trace}((A+D)^{-1}A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, trace

Give a diagonal perturbation matrix $D$ (which is **not** an identity matrix), is there a simple way to compute

> $$\text{trace}((A+D)^{-1}A)$$

Or is there a good approximation?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible and $\|D\|$ is small, $(A+D)^{-1}A=(I+A^{-1}D)^{-1}\approx I-A^{-1}D$ and hence $\operatorname{trace}\left((A+D)^{-1}A\right)\approx n-\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}D)$.

Comment: I was just about to say the same with one small addition. For the last term, I think, you can derive some estimate $|\operatorname{Tr}(A^{-1}D)|=|A^{-T}:D|\leq\|A^{-1}\|_F\|D\|_F$, where $:$ is the Frobenius inner product and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @ElmarZander Thanks, it's a useful addition.

Comment: @user1551, I am just curious. What does it mean when you put $\approx$ between two matrices?

Comment: @user60079 It means the matrix norm of their difference is small.